# VBA script issue specifying command line

Tags: excel, vba, command-prompt

So I'm fairly new to VBA, using it within some spreadsheets so forgive me if this is a super obvious fix, I'm sure it is but have spent hours on with with no success.

The following piece of code will lie inside of an if statement - not sure if thats worth mentioning or not.

I want to simply move, and rename files from one location to the other
It needs to utilize cmd.exe, and use the 'move' argument -  the source path and source destinations will be changeable depending on the pc - so it will need to use the '%temp% - as the initial file will be stored in this folder, and %userprofile% for the destination path.

Here is the code so far - I think the issue is just to do with the formatting -

```
Sub movefile ()

Dim Origpath As String
Dim NewPath As String

OrigPath="%temp%\newfile.txt"
NewPath="%userprofile%`Documents\newfile.vbs"

<<next code inside of an if statement>>

moveFile="C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /C move " & OrigPath & " " &  NewPath

End Sub
```

Maybe the " and & arent placed correctly? But the code works fine up until the line 'movefile...'

Probably a super easy way of doing it - help please!!

Comment: Isn't this what [`Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-statement) does? It looks like you could use `Environ$` to get those paths: `Environ$("temp")` and `Environ("UserProfile")`.

Comment: `moveFile="C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /C move """ & OrigPath & """ """ &  NewPath & """"`  in case of spaces in the paths, and you seem to have a typo in your `NewPath` value: backtick instead of backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Name`:

```
name OrigPath as  NewPath
```

Alternatively you can use use fdo movefile, as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38461437/78522).