# VBA to save multiple PDF files from one location to another

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, copy, save

I would like to use Excel VBA to copy multiple (157) PDF's from various locations (I have all the paths) and simply save them into one location.

I'm very much a beginner with VBA and need some assistance, hopefully its quite simple.

I tried myself and got as far as using the .FollowHyperlink method although this opens the document which would not be practical for 157 documents. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Great to see that you're trying to learn how to code with vba.

I think it is possible in VBA.
Try and take a look at [move files from one folder to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456928/move-files-from-one-folder-to-another) the question is about moving .xlsx files but if you change the .xlsx to .pdf it should work

from my personal experience I don't like using vba for this kind of job.

You could try other coding languages like python.