# Excel vba to save Word file in location - running slow

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, ms-office

I have the following code that I'm going to build on to eventually ask the user whether they want to save a word document in a file location. But for the time being just testing out something really simple. The code however takes around 9-10 seconds to run. I appreciate the saving is happening on a network drive but even so the Word document is only 75kb big. Is there a quicker way of doing what I want to do?

```
Sub WordSaveAs()
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim wdRng As Word.Range

Dim SaveName As String
Dim FileExt As String

Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

With wdApp

Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open("[file location.docx]")
End With

SaveName = "[new file location.docx]" & FileExt

wdApp.DisplayAlerts = True
wdDoc.SaveAs SaveName

wdDoc.Close
Set wdDoc = Nothing

wdApp.Quit

Set wdApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

EDIT:

Thanks to @RaymondWu they have copied in a link below and i have used the following code instead:

```
Sub MoveFiles()
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim SourceFileName As String, DestinFileName As String

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
    SourceFileName = "file location.docx"
    DestinFileName = "new file location.docx"

    FSO.CopyFile Source:=SourceFileName, Destination:=DestinFileName

    MsgBox (SourceFileName + " copied to " + DestinFileName)
End Sub
```

Comment: The time taken should be due to you creating a new instance of Word which is unavoidable as far as I know (You don't expect Word to open instantly when you open Word normally right?)

Comment: Yes, that's true. Unless there's a way to do it without opening word? e.g. if i were to do this manually then I could copy and paste the file using windows explorer..

Comment: so basically you are moving file only? Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456928/move-files-from-one-folder-to-another) help? The answer shows `MoveFile` method but there's a `CopyFile` method which is similar in syntax

Comment: @RaymondWu yes this has helped - i've edited the question with the code i used but cannot give you the "answer" as it's written in a comment!

Comment: That's fine! This is more like a duplicate question so i don't think there's a need for an answer